# XSLT :XSL:Number to start from 0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to increment a number using `<xsl:number level="single"/>`. However I need count to start from 0 instead of 1.

Sample Input:

```
<name>
<Sequence>Id</Sequence>
<Field1>A1</Field1>
<Field2<A2</Field2>
</name>
<name>
<Sequence>Id</Sequence>
<Field1>A1</Field1>
<Field2<A2</Field2>
</name>
```

Sample output:

```
<name>
<Sequence>Id0</Sequence>
<Field1>A1</Field1>
<Field2<A2</Field2>
</name>
<name>
<Sequence>Id1</Sequence>
<Field1>A1</Field1>
<Field2<A2</Field2>
</name>
```

XSLT Snippet:

```
<name>
<Sequence>
Id<xsl:number level="single"/></Sequence>
------
</name>
```

which generates Id1 & Id2 instead of Id0 & Id1. I could not use position() for some reason. Is it possible to have an arithmetic operation like -1 etc for eg: Id`<xsl:number level="single"/>` -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#number has a `start-at` attribute. You can of course also use `<xsl:variable name="n"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="$n - 1"/>`.

Comment: And the choice will depend on which library you have doing the transform. Outside of Saxon, I'm not sure how many support 3.0.